# Codeigniter Table Library Handle Empty / Null Values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter 3 and the [table library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html) in order to display some data in the following format;

```
+---------------+---------------------+
| id            | 102                 |
+---------------+---------------------+
| First Name    | Ross                |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Last Name     | Bing                |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Title         | Doctor              |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Timestamp     | 2019-01-18 10:17:05 |
+---------------+---------------------+
| Member Number |                     |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

A vardump of `$tableData` is;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 102
            [firstname] => Ross
            [lastname] => Bing
            [title] => Doctor
            [timestamp] => 2019-01-18 10:17:05
            [member_no] => 
        )
)
```

The PHP code I use to generate the HTML table is;

```
$tableData = $this->My_model->getData();

$heading = array(
    'id' => 'ID',
    'firstname' => 'First Name',
    'lastname' => 'Last Name',
    'title' => 'Title',
    'timestamp' => 'Date Submitted',
    'member_no' => 'Member Number'
);

$fields = array_keys($tableData[0]);
$rows = array();

foreach($fields as $key => $field) {
    $rows[$key][0] = array(
        'data' => '<strong>' . $heading[$field] . '</strong>'
    );
    foreach($tableData as $key2 => $item) {
        $rows[$key][$key2 + 1] = $item[$field];
    }
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $this->table->add_row($row);
}
```

The above code works fine, however if a row is empty (see `member_no` above) i'd like to do one of two things (whichever is easiest);

- hide the table row completely
- display `not available` in the table cell

How can I achieve this?

Comment: something like: $rows[$key][$key2 + 1] = ($item[$field!=''])?$item[$field]:'not available'

Comment: I find these 3 foreach loops to be `ugly`.  Sorry but they are.  You could probably do some `array_intersect_key` and `array_merge` magic to get rid of a few of those.

Comment: I would need an example of the input and output data, such as what `$tableData` looks like and what `$rows` looks like.  An example here is when you use `array_merge` with string keys, the data in the second array replaces the data in the first, but the order of the keys in the first array is preserved.  You could also `array_filter` the input data, removing any empty values, then pre-populate an array (with `not available`)  with the keys matched to the `$header` array, then when you merge them anything that was removed from the filter retains the default value... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$tableData = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'id' => 102,
        'lastname' => 'Bing',
        'title' => 'Doctor',
        'timestamp' => '2019-01-1810:17:05',
        'member_no' => null,
        'firstname' => 'Ross', //intentionally moved to show ordering
        'foobar' => 'blah' //added for example, this will be removed by array_intersect_key
    ),
);

$heading = array(
    'id' => '<strong>ID</strong>',
    'firstname' => '<strong>First Name</strong>',
    'lastname' => '<strong>Last Name</strong>',
    'title' => '<strong>Title</strong>',
    'timestamp' => '<strong>Date Submitted</strong>',
    'member_no' => '<strong>Member Number</strong>'
);

//create a default array
//this takes the keys from $heading, and makes an array with all the values as 'not available'
// ['id' => 'not available','lastname' => 'not available', ... ]
$default = array_fill_keys(array_keys($heading), 'not available');
$rows = [];

foreach($tableData as $key => $row) {
    //remove all elements with strlen of 0 (in this case 'member_no')
    $row = array_filter($row, function($item){return strlen($item);});

    //removes 'foobar' or anything that has a key not in $heading
    $row = array_intersect_key($row, $heading);

    //combine $default and $data (empty items in $row are filled in from default)
    //such as items removed by array_filter above
    //the key order will match $default, which matches $headings
    $row = array_merge($default, $row);

    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($heading as $key=>$value) {
    print_r(array_merge([['data'=>$value]], array_column($rows, $key)));
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => <strong>ID</strong>
        )

    [1] => 102
    //[2] => 108
    //...
)
 ....
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a9ebf94d6691028d4e0fd19fa7298277a98d1d37)

I kept these separate so it would be a bit easier to read, but there is no reason you cannot do it this way.

```
//...
$default = array_fill_keys(array_keys($heading), 'not available');

foreach($tableData as $key => $row) $rows[] = array_merge($default, array_intersect_key(array_filter($row, function($item){return strlen($item);}), $heading));

foreach($heading as $key=>$value) print_r(array_merge([['data'=>$value]],array_column($rows, $key)));
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f84246a02c5fee0692bded3952a3c7c2f772c57)

I had to guess a bit on what the end result was, so I ran your original code and it gave me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => <strong>ID</strong>
        )

    [1] => 102
    //[2] => 108
    //...
)
....
```

In my code you can replace the `print_r` with this call `$this->table->add_row([..array data..]);`.  Where `array data` is the stuff in the `print_r` call.  You could make this a variable, but what's the point if its only used here.  That eliminates a few of those loops (see below) and A few other advantages:

- key order of `$headings` is preserved, elements appear where they do in the `$headings` array, regardless of where they are in `$tableData`. This allows easy re-ording of the data, too, for example: you could even map this to a dynamic array, I do this in CSV files, which allows users to change the order of the headers and columns. They can even rename the headers, because the way the `key => value` pairing works  `my_key => their_key`...
- Data missing from `$tableData` is defaulted to `not available` pulled in from `$default`, in theory you could map this manually to different things.   For example: you could default timestamp to the current time by doing `$default['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` right after creating it with `array_fill_keys`.
- Extra data in `$tableData` not defined in `$headings` is removed.  Which is good for forward compatibility.
- And it's A bit easier to make sense of (once you know how it works) because there are less "transient" variables and less fiddling with the keys ect...

Basically what I am doing is giving control over to the `$headings` array, in your original code. You do this somewhat by looping over the keys (`fields`), but this complicates things later like this `$rows[$key][$key2 + 1]`.  It leaves you open to undefined array index issues, if the data changes at a later time, such as adding a new field to the DB.
The order of the output is dependent on the data in `$tableData` which is less intuitive (and less useful) then if it depends on `$headings`.

Here is an example of these issues with the original code:

```
//for example if your data changes to this and run your original code
 $tableData = array (
 0 => 
    array (
        'id' => 102,
        'lastname' => 'Bing',
        'title' => 'Doctor',
        'timestamp' => '2019-01-1810:17:05',
        'member_no' => null,
        'firstname' => 'Ross', //intentionally moved to show ordering
        'foo' => 'bar' //added this undefined in $headings
    ),
);
```

You'll get this notice and also find the last 2 elements are:

```
 <br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: foo in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
 //... all other elements ...

 //in orignal: displayed in the order of $tableData
 //in my code: order is based on $headings, so this would be moved to the correct location
Array(
    [0] => Array (
         [data] => <strong>First Name</strong>
    )        
    [1] => Ross
)

//in orignal: $headings['foo'] is not defined so we have no label here
//in my code: this element is removed and doesn't get rendered
Array(
     [0] => Array(
           [data] => <strong></strong>
      )

     [1] => bar
)
```

[Sandbox (Orignal Code)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3f011644532a8b792eb157959a920cd937d4b6a)

While these things may never cause an issue, it highlights my point about basing the output off of `$headings` and not `$tableData`. Things tend to change, and this way if you add/remove a field from this data, you wont have to worry about it breaking this page etc...

The combination of `array_fill_keys`, `array_intersect_key` and `array_merge` can be used to map the headers (As I shown above) of one array to another.  You can use `array_combine($headings, $row)` to physically swap them and you would get something like this:

```
[
     [
         '<strong>ID</strong>' => 102,
         '<strong>First Name</strong>' => 'Ross',
          //...
     ],
     [...]
]
```

It works great for CSV files (which is what I figured it out on) and anything else you need to remap the keys for.

Anyway, hope it helps you!

Comment: Hey @ArtisticPhoenix - this is one of the best answers on SO, it definitely helps me! Thanks very much for the detailed explanation, it all makes much more sense now!

Comment: It's a bit more complicated if you don't fully understand the functions that I use in this and how they work together.  But it works really nice, I do a lot with CSV files that our users submit (we run them against a DB, and return a report).  So we had to make a way to customize the headers (names, order ) etc... and I came up with the basic method of what I did above because of that...   Thanks!